# SQL table join based on aggregated/equal values

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have a *very* horrible two table dataset to hand that I need to create a join query for. Its best to show an example:

```
+------+---------+-----------+--+
| Time | Sent    | Received  |  |
+------+---------+-----------+--+
|    1 | 100     | NULL      |  |
|    2 | NULL    | 100       |  |
|    3 | 50      | NULL      |  |
|    4 | NULL    | 40        |  |
|    5 | NULL    | 10        |  |
|    6 | 400     | 200       |  |
|    7 | 100     | 200       |  |
|    8 | NULL    | 100       |  |
|    9 | 500     | 500       |  |
+------+---------+-----------+--+
```

Assuming 'time' above is in hours - 'Sent' shows the number of items sent in that hour, and 'Received' shows the number received. The problem being that they likely will not arrive in the same hour they were sent (though they *can*).

I need to match the received against the appropriate sent to **find the time the received item was Sent**.

Using the above:

- Received 100 at time 2 is obviously the items sent from hour 1, so
  that would be assigned to hour 1.
- 50 Sent in time 3 arrived in two batches (40 and 10 in time 4/5 respectively). So received 40/10 should be lumped into the time 3 category
- Received in 6/7 (each for 200) correspond to the 400 order in time 6 (note that half the order was received in the same hour, this can happen)
- Also in time 7 a new order was sent which corresponds to received for time 8
- Also in time 9 an order of 500 was sent and received in the same hour.

Below is an example of what the output would look like (Note that there are other values associated with each 'Received' row but they are orthogonal to the task and will just be summed to provide meaning)

```
    +------+----------+
    | Time | Received |
    +------+----------+
    |    1 |      100 |
    |    3 |       50 |
    |    6 |      400 |
    |    7 |      100 |
    |    8 |      100 |
    |    9 |      500 |
    +------+----------+
```

I have been trying to rack my head around this for a while. If I could do this outside of sql I would have some function that loops through the value for each 'Sent' incrementally through time and loop that through 'Received' until the values match then assign those Received values to the Time index, then delete both the sent and received from the array (or note where the loop got to and continue from there)

Unfortunately the project doesnt allow the that scope - This must be done as much in SQL as possible. I am really at a loss and hoping there is some SQL functionality I have overlooked. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: 1. Why does your desired output have `9   400` and not `9   500`?

Comment: 2. How is your desired output different than just `SELECT Time, Sent AS Received FROM tbl WHERE Received IS NOT NULL`?  I do understand what you are saying about matching sent and received, but your output doesn't really show it.

Comment: @RossPresser I think that would yield the wrong times

Comment: I don't think you'll get anywhere without writing out your defined rules and making a SQL statement for each rule. I think doing all your logic in one script will be a pain. Instead, write out what you need it to do and store each manipulation to a temp table. In the end join all your temp tables to get your desired results.

Comment: @RossPresser, totally right sorry, have fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in SQL Server, you can use a `WHILE` loop. Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql). So, your project might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([Time] int, [Received] int)
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @value int = 0
WHILE @i <= 9
BEGIN
    @value = SELECT [Received] FROM [table] WHERE [Time] = @i
    --Your logic here
    INSERT INTO #temp ...
END
SELECT * FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Ah this could work! I wasn't aware SQL had loop functionality like this. I think I can make something work

Comment: Looks like I can loop through table values too, so that may be the way forward. Thanks

Comment: I recommend not using loops whenever possible- they can get really slow.